# Multiple virtual network devices on windows

Tags: windows, sockets, networking

I'm trying to find a way to simulate a small network of devices on Windows such that I have multiple instances of a process that bind to *different* IPv4 addresses on the same port to receive+ respond to UDP broadcast packets.

Goal being to emulate existing devices that do this and test a small device discovery protocol.

Ideally... using simple Python script that does something like this for "device":

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# bind to subnet broadcast address
s.bind(("192.168.10.255", 5555))

#get discovery request
s.recvfrom(...)

#send discovery response 
s.sendto(...)
```

Each endpoint would than also host a TCP service on same port, different IP.

But.... I'm not sure what's possible here in terms of having multiple instances of this running with different IPs on the same subnet.

Is running a VM for each simulated endpoint the only way?